# JQuery work only in the first element of a list

Tags: jquery, firefox

I am a designer and I don't know much about jQuery and I am stuck at this problem for the past 5 days 
please take a look at the page that has the problem.
http://osama.me/blog/?cat=5

the yellow button above every image doesn't work except for the first image :( . I tested this gallery page in the local host before uploading the site using firefox 3.6 and all buttons working fine. I am facing this problem only on the internet and with the same firefox 3.6 . 
the buttons work fine in other browsers

I hope someone will help me or give me a clue
and sorry for my bad english

Comment: That site is blocked where I work but it would be helpful if you could post the code in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Your English is good.  This works for me in Firefox 3.6 and Chrome 7.  Are you getting some sort of error message?

Comment: no, I am using firebug and there is no errors, I tried the site in 2 other computers but the the results are the same :(

Comment: the problem is that I don't have any error messages for a certain file so I don't know which code to put although that I read in some sites that .each method may help accessing many element

Comment: sorry, maybe this code is what you are asking for:   $(document).ready(function(){

 $(".thumbnail-div .info-button").click(function(){
   $(this).prev(".info").slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
 });


 $(".bar .rating").click(function(){
   $(this).prev(".ratingbox").slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
 });
 
 $(".post-wrapper .lightboxclick").click(function(){
   $(this).prev(".lightbox").slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
 });

});

Answer (score 0):

The yellow arrow button that triggers the pulldown is working fine for me in Firefox 3.6.12.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a browser javascript caching trouble. Just try to empty you cache pressing shift + ctrl + suppr. It should do the trick.

Comment: This was my first thought.  Restarting Firefox should do the trick as well.  This is why I test in private mode a lot - in Firefox and Chrome.  Caching is not an issue then.

Comment: I tried clearing the whole history and restarting the browser but sadly it didn't work except for the second image which is working now but I am not sure if it was working before clearing the history or not

Comment: I am not sure about the fact that browsing in private mode on Firefox or Chrome disable or purge the javascript cache. Restarting the browser too. You can also attempt refreshing by pressing shift + ctrl + r in order to force the reloading of the cached files (images, javascript, css ...)